# How to do an action when an order is filled?

Tags: pine-script

```
strategy.order("long tp", strategy.short, 1, longTP, alert_message=alert)
```

When "long tp" is filled it sends me an alert message. Is it possible to do a different action when this order is filled, like set `color = color.blue` ? What expression do I need to achieve this: if the order "long tp" is filled, `color := color.blue`

Answer (score 3):

If order was filled then the strategy position was changed. You can monitor the strategy position change and react on this. The example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

someOrderFilled = strategy.position_size != strategy.position_size[1]
plotshape(someOrderFilled, style=shape.xcross)
```

Comment: That is true, but the strategy is calculating on close. someOrderFilled wont plot until the candle closes. Is it possible to do an action as soon as the order is filled, like the alert? (without setting calc_on_every_tick to true)

Comment: There are another option - calc_on_order_fills

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I guess it can't be done without changing the calculation type.